# DatePickerDialog opening with previous opened screen

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Hello I am using DatePickerDialog and its working as expected.

Below is my code.

```
    Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    dobDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(this, new OnDateSetListener() {

        public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

            if (view.isShown()) {
                //view.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
                Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
                dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
                int year1 = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int year2 = dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                int age = year1 - year2;

                if (age <= 18) {
                    Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, MyUtils.getStringFromResource(EditProfileActivity.this, R.string.validate_date_18_above), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    dobFld.setText("");
                } else {
                    isDataChanged = true;
                    dobFld.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));

                }

            }
        }

    }, newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dobDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
    dobDatePickerDialog.updateDate(birthYear,birthMonth-1,birthDay);

}
```

It is showing me selected date. But the problem is that If I click on  year option (on top of dialog) to change the year and then cancel or press OK button without changing year value. Then dialog get cloesed. But next time if I open the picker,it is opening on year view not in the initial calendar view..

Below is my code to intiate the dialog.

```
 dobFld = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.dobFld);
    dobFld.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_NULL);
    dobFld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dobDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

Please give me some clue how to initialize picker so that it opens with calendar view as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I have solve the problem. I am posting as may be it could help other.
Just create new object on every time button click.

```
 dobFld.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            Calendar newCalendar = Calendar.getInstance();

            dobDatePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(EditProfileActivity.this,EditProfileActivity.this,newCalendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), newCalendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), newCalendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

            dobDatePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
            dobDatePickerDialog.updateDate(birthYear,birthMonth-1,birthDay);
            dobDatePickerDialog.show();
        }
    });
```

and below will be dateSet method

```
 @Override
public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {

    if (view.isShown()) {
        //view.setMaxDate(new Date().getTime());
        Calendar dob = Calendar.getInstance();
        dob.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
        Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year1 = now.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int year2 = dob.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int age = year1 - year2;

        if (age <= 18) {
            Toast.makeText(EditProfileActivity.this, MyUtils.getStringFromResource(EditProfileActivity.this, R.string.validate_date_18_above), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            dobFld.setText("");
        } else {
            isDataChanged = true;
            dobFld.setText(dateFormatter.format(dob.getTime()));

        }

    }
```